# How to display a span if the field have an information else no display with React JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I need to display the icon when the field no empty else we display empty field without the icon of close

```
{
  this.state.showIcon ? (
    <span
      style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
      onClick={() => {
        this.props.handleChangeAnyInput("", `exercice_${item.id}`);
      }}
    >
      X
    </span>
  ) : (
    ""
  );
}
```

Comment: Your code is correct, just change `) : ( "" );` by `) : ( <span></span> );` to hold <p> space

Comment: Any answer please

Comment: Hi. IMO this does not meet the criteria on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please add the expected behavior, and what you are getting instead.

Answer (score 0):

here is the working code

```
{
            this.state.showIcon ? 
              <span
                style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                onClick={() => {
                  this.props.handleChangeAnyInput("", `exercice_${item.id}`);
                }}
              >
</span>
             : 
              ""
          }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but also I need when the field has the file,  the icon to close exist